# Calculate Average Time Between Sound Frquency Peaks in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

You analyze track x at 10 frequency levels. You set up a loop that monitors if the level of a certain frequency has reached a certain level. You output and store a boolean with an associated time value. You calculate the average distance in frames between true boolean values. This value can be used to modulate other values in sync with the music.

Say we bake a house music track, one with a fairly regular distribution of waveform peaks. When you discern the average number of frames between one kick drum hit and the next, you could use this number to synchronize animations with the music.

Here is a discussion of the essential elements of the process. http://mziccard.me/2015/05/28/beats-detection-algorithms-1/

> The first algorithm I will talk about was originally presented here. I implemented it in the class SoundEnergyBPMDetector. The algorithm divides the data into blocks of samples and compares the energy of a block with the energy of a preceding window of blocks. The energy of a block is used to detect a beat. If the energy is above a certain threshold then the block is considered to contain a beat. The threshold is defined starting from the average energy of the window of blocks preceding the one we are analyzing.
>
> If a block j is made of 1024 samples and the song is stereo, its energy can be computed as:
>
> Ej=∑i=01023left[i]2+right[i]2
> The block’s energy is then placed in a circular buffer that stores all the energy values for the current window. Let us assume that the current window is made of 43 blocks (43⋅1024=44032 ~ 1s with a sample rate of 44100), the average window energy can be computed as:
>
> avg(E)=143∑j=042Ej
> We detect a beat if the instant energy Ej is bigger than C⋅avg(E). In the original article, a way to compute C is proposed as a linear regression of the energy variance in the corresponding window. In the SoundEnergyBPMDetector class I use a slightly modified equation that lowers the impact of variance:
>
> C=−0.0000015⋅var(E)+1.5142857
> In general, however, the bigger the variance the more likely we consider a block to be a beat. The variance inside a window of blocks is defined as:

This implementation should have some means of setting the sample size, i.e. how many frames you want to be analyzed.

Comment: I don't think this question is particularly on topic. While anything can be done in AN, this question is asking *how* to detect the BPM which is something that is more suitable for DSP.SE. Don't you think?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about an algorithm to detect BPM from a discrete signal, I think this is mote suitable for dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I was thinking of something along the lines of finding an average time between spikes in the audio frequency levels created by the bake sounds node. A real bpm detection algorithm would be very complex, and possibly out of the range of AN, but I do think the deriving some rate between frequency spikes is not out of the question @OmarAhmad

Comment: I don't know, maybe you can edit your question to incorporate the implementation details so that we can help.